# Probability that 3 out of 4 sets have non-empty intersection

Tags: probability, sampling, combinatorics, subset

I have $4$ randomly sampled subsets from population set $S = \{1,2,...,100\}$. Each subset has size $24$.

What is the probability that at least one element is common among $3$ out of $4$ subsets?

Comment: How were they sampled, exactly?  Shall we presume each is a simple random sample without replacement and that the four subsets were obtained independently?  By "3 out of 4" do you mean *some 3 of the 4 but not all 4* or *at least 3 of the 4*?

Comment: @whuber, yes correct presumption. All 4 are sampled independently without replacement. By "3 out of 4" I mean at least 3 of the 4.